# Can't figure out how to edit powershell script

Tags: powershell

This script collects information about Local Machine certificates and show days when cert expires (in JSON).

```
{ "{#CERTINFO}" : "@{Expires in (Days)=8074}" }
```

I need is only need `8074` (days) and can't figure out how to edit this script.

```
$cert_ = get-childitem cert:LocalMAchine -recurse |
where-object {$_.NotAfter -gt (get-date)} |
select @{Name="Expires in (Days)";Expression={($_.NotAfter).subtract([DateTime]::Now).days}} |
Sort "Expires in (Days)"

write-host "{"
write-host " `"data`":[`n"
$idx = 1
foreach ($cert_arr in $cert_ )
{
if ($idx -lt $cert_.Count)

{
$line= "{ `"{#CERTINFO}`" : `"" + $cert_arr + "`" },"  
write-host $line 
}
elseif ($idx -ge $cert_.Count)
{
$line= "{ `"{#CERTINFO}`" : `"" + $cert_arr + "`" }"
write-host $line 
}
$idx++;
}
write-host
write-host " ]"
write-host "}"
```

Comment: That's a quite awful way to write PowerShell. Maybe you should simply start over (and in the process learn something about the language).

Comment: What did you try? Start with removing all write-host statements.

Comment: Yeah i'm understand that : >

Comment: When i change select to select @{Name=" ";Expression={($_.NotAfter).subtract([DateTime]::Now).days}}
Result is:{ "{#CERTINFO}" : "@{ =8074}" },

Comment: I need write-host to get JSON format for Zabbix

PS C:\Scripts> C:\Scripts\cert_check.ps1

{
 "data":[

{ "{#CERTINFO}" : "@{Expires in (Days)=8074}" }

 ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```html
function Get-CertInfo
{

    $cert_ = get-childitem cert:LocalMAchine -recurse | where-object {$_.NotAfter -gt (get-date)} | select @{Name="Expires in (Days)";Expression={($_.NotAfter).subtract([DateTime]::Now).days}} | Sort "Expires in (Days)"

    $data = @()

    foreach($c in $cert_)
    {
        $entry = [PSObject]@{"#CERTINFO"="$c"}

        $data += $entry
    }

    $certInfor = [PSObject]@{"data"=$data}

    $certInfor | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

That generates:

```
{
"data":  [
             {
                 "#CERTINFO":  "@{Expires in (Days)=221}"
             },
             {
                 "#CERTINFO":  "@{Expires in (Days)=272}"
             }
         ]
}
```

Hope that helps.